# Cloud Build Trigger - Not in Firebase app directory error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

I have problem with deploying node.js (Angular) application from Bitbucket repository to Firebase using Cloud Build Trigger.
I performed steps from this article - https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase

- Necessary APIs are turned on,
- Service account has all required permissions,
- Firebase community builder is deployed and visible in Container Registry,
- Cloudbuild.json file is added to repository,
- Cloud Build Trigger is created and it points to one specific branch of my repository.

Problem is that after running Cloud Build Trigger I receive following error: "Error: Not in Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)"

What could be reason of such error? Is it possible to point to the trigger where in repository is firebase application and firebase.json file?

EDIT:
My cloudbuild.json file is quite simple:

```
{
  "steps": [
   {
      "name": "gcr.io/PROJECT_NAME/firebase",
      "args": [
         "deploy",
         "--project",
         "PROJECT_NAME",
         "--only",
         "functions"
       ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Logs in Cloud Build Trigger history:

```
  starting build "build_id"

FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/link
 * branch            branch_id -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at d8bc2f1 Add cloudbuild.json file
BUILD
Pulling image: gcr.io/PROJECT/firebase
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling PROJECT/firebase
1e987daa2432: Already exists
a0edb687a3da: Already exists
6891892cc2ec: Already exists
684eb726ddc5: Already exists
b0af097f0da6: Already exists
154aee36a7da: Already exists
37e5835696f7: Pulling fs layer
62eb6e670f1d: Pulling fs layer
47e62615d9f9: Pulling fs layer
428cea824ccd: Pulling fs layer
765a2c722bf9: Pulling fs layer
b3f5d0a285e3: Pulling fs layer
428cea824ccd: Waiting
765a2c722bf9: Waiting
b3f5d0a285e3: Waiting
47e62615d9f9: Verifying Checksum
47e62615d9f9: Download complete
62eb6e670f1d: Verifying Checksum
62eb6e670f1d: Download complete
765a2c722bf9: Verifying Checksum
765a2c722bf9: Download complete
b3f5d0a285e3: Verifying Checksum
b3f5d0a285e3: Download complete
37e5835696f7: Verifying Checksum
37e5835696f7: Download complete
428cea824ccd: Verifying Checksum
428cea824ccd: Download complete
37e5835696f7: Pull complete
62eb6e670f1d: Pull complete
47e62615d9f9: Pull complete
428cea824ccd: Pull complete
765a2c722bf9: Pull complete
b3f5d0a285e3: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:4b6b7214d6344c8247130bf3f5443a2851e39aed3ececb32dfb2cc25a5c07e44
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/PROJECT/firebase:latest
gcr.io/PROJECT/firebase:latest

Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/PROJECT/firebase" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Firebase.json file is placed in repository in following path: /apps/firebase/firebase.json
I can't see any possibility to point that path in Cloud Build Trigger config.

Comment: Can you share your cloudbuild.json, at least the part that fail? I can help you to debug that. In addition, did you try to run Cloud Build with the CLI? From which directory?

Comment: I have editted my post. I ran Cloud Build from CLI when pushing the firebase community builder. I did it from "apps/firebase" path. In that case the firebase community builder was submitted without any problems and it is visible in my project in Container Registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you aren't in the correct directory when you run the command. To check this, you can add this step

```
{
  "steps": [
   {
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud",
      "entrypoint":"ls"
      "args": ["-la"]
  }
  ]
}
```

If you aren't in the correct directory, and you need to be in the `./app/firebase` to run your deploy, you can add this parameter in your step

```
{
  "steps": [
   {
      "name": "gcr.io/PROJECT_NAME/firebase",
      "dir": "app/firebase",
      "args": [
         "deploy",
         "--project",
         "PROJECT_NAME",
         "--only",
         "functions"
       ]
  }
  ]
}
```

Let me know if it's better

Comment: Adding dir parameter helps. Thanks.
But now I have another eror:
`
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
 
> lint
> tslint --project tsconfig.json
 
sh: 1: tslint: not found
 
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code127
`
I think it is connected with function in predeploy array in firebase,json file. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not a Node developer and so I don't know. However, are you sure that all your environment variable (here RESOURCE_DIR) are all correctly set?

Comment: Problem solved by adding first step with npm install command in cloudbuild.json file.
Thank you for help.